# How to go to a child route by route name?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I know we can go to a route by its name using `$router.push({ name: 'route-name' })`.

What I want to know is how to do that with a `child route name`.
This is my route structure:

```js
export default [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: () => import('@/views/Home.vue'),
    childs: [
      {
        name: 'home.about',
        path: '/about',
        component: import('@/views/Home/About.vue')
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

But my console says `[vue-router] Route with name 'home.about' does not exist` for `$router.push({ name: 'home.about' })`.

What I'm missing?

Obs: The idea is to not route to the child using a hard `route path`.

Comment: Add exact to the perticular router

Comment: Where do I put the `exact` properly?

Comment: You need to put it inside <router-link>: here is [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#exact)

Comment: There's no `<router-link>`. I'm talking about `$router`

Comment: First, could you please check the name should be "children" instead of "child". Secondly, please try removing "/" from children route like "about".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo.

It should be `children` and not `childs`.

```
export default [
{
  path: '/',
  name: 'home',
  component: () => import('@/views/Home.vue'),
  children: [
   {
    name: 'home.about',
    path: '/about',
    component: import('@/views/Home/About.vue')
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [{ 
        path: '/foo',
        name: 'foo',
        component: Foo,
        children: [
        {
          path: 'fooChild1',
          name: 'fooChild1',
          component: FooChildComponent
        },
        {
          path: 'fooChild2',
          name: 'fooChild2',
          component: FooChildComponent
        }
      ]
    }, { 
        path: '/bar', 
        component: Bar
    }]
})
```

Now if you wish to navigate to `fooChild1` then use $router.push({ name: 'fooChild1' }) or if you wish to navigate to `fooChild2` then use $router.push({ name: 'fooChild2' })